# Asterisk and isdn bri card give me error 3302 isdn

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to configure a b410p card with asterisk.
I have attached a phone isdn to the NT port of the card. This is my configuration

/etc/dahdi/system.conf

```
# Span 1: B4/0/1 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" AMI/CCS RED 
span=1,0,0,ccs,ami
# termtype: nt
bchan=1-2
hardhdlc=3
echocanceller=mg2,1-2
# Span 2: B4/0/2 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" AMI/CCS RED 
span=2,0,0,ccs,ami
# termtype: nt
bchan=4-5
hardhdlc=6
echocanceller=mg2,4-5
# Span 3: B4/0/3 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3" AMI/CCS RED 
span=3,0,0,ccs,ami
# termtype: nt
bchan=7-8
hardhdlc=9
echocanceller=mg2,7-8
# Span 4: B4/0/4 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4" (MASTER) AMI/CCS 
span=4,0,0,ccs,ami
# termtype: nt
bchan=10-11
hardhdlc=12
echocanceller=mg2,10-11
```

/etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

```
[trunkgroups]
[channels]
language=it
context=local
switchtype=euroisdn
signalling=bri_net_ptmp
usecallerid=yes
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
context= incoming
echocancel=yes
channel => 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
group=1
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
```

#include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf

/etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf

```
; Span 1: B4/0/1 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" AMI/CCS RED 
group=0,11
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 1-2
context = default
group = 63
; Span 2: B4/0/2 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" AMI/CCS RED 
group=0,12
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 4-5
context = default
group = 63
; Span 3: B4/0/3 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3" AMI/CCS RED 
group=0,13
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 7-8
context = default
group = 63
; Span 4: B4/0/4 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4" (MASTER) AMI/CCS 
group=0,14
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 10-11
context = default
group = 63
```

The port with the phone attached is green, so is OK

dahdi_tool said:

```
RED             B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1                       ↑  │ 
                          │     RED             B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2                       ▒  │ 
                          │     RED             B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3                       ▮  │ 
                          │     OK              B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4
```

From the isdn phone I try to call the 200 test extensions and exit with the isdn error code 3302

this is my extensions.conf part

```
exten => 200,1,Answer()
same => n,Playback(hello-world)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => 1000,1,Dial(dahdi/4,20)
```

When i try to call "1000" from console said

```
 Span 2: Channel 0/1 got hangup, cause 18
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i2/-2'
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'ALSA/default' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'
  << Hangup on console >>
```

Some advice? Thanks

Pri debug report this(i have changed the extension from 1000 to 039991122 and extensions.conf

```
039991122
    -- Executing [039991122@local:1] Dial("ALSA/default", "DAHDI/g14/039991122") in new stack
PRI Span: 4 -- Making new call for cref 32773
    -- Requested transfer capability: 0x00 - SPEECH
PRI Span: 4 Sending message for call 0x7f0d84008b20 on call->link: 0x782140 with TEI/SAPI 127/63
PRI Span: 4 
PRI Span: 4 > Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=26
PRI Span: 4 > TEI=127 Call Ref: len= 1 (reference 5/0x5) (Sent from originator)
PRI Span: 4 > Message Type: SETUP (5)
PRI Span: 4 > [04 03 80 90 a3]
PRI Span: 4 > Bearer Capability (len= 5) [ Ext: 1  Coding-Std: 0  Info transfer capability: Speech (0)
PRI Span: 4 >                              Ext: 1  Trans mode/rate: 64kbps, circuit-mode (16)
PRI Span: 4 >                                User information layer 1: A-Law (35)
PRI Span: 4 > [18 01 89]
PRI Span: 4 > Channel ID (len= 3) [ Ext: 1  IntID: Implicit  BRI  Spare: 0  Exclusive  Dchan: 0
PRI Span: 4 >                       ChanSel: B1 channel
PRI Span: 4 >                     ]
PRI Span: 4 > [70 0b 80 30 37 38 34 33 36 36 35 30 38]
PRI Span: 4 > Called Party Number (len=13) [ Ext: 1  TON: Unknown Number Type (0)  NPI: Unknown Number Plan (0)  '039991122' ]
PRI Span: 4 > [a1]
PRI Span: 4 > Sending Complete (len= 1)
PRI Span: 4 q931.c:6531 q931_setup: Call 32773 enters state 1 (Call Initiated).  Hold state: Idle
    -- Called DAHDI/g14/039991122
PRI Span: 4 T303 timed out.  cref:32773
PRI Span: 4 Sending message for call 0x7f0d84008b20 on call->link: 0x782140 with TEI/SAPI 127/63
PRI Span: 4 
PRI Span: 4 > Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=26
PRI Span: 4 > TEI=127 Call Ref: len= 1 (reference 5/0x5) (Sent from originator)
PRI Span: 4 > Message Type: SETUP (5)
PRI Span: 4 > [04 03 80 90 a3]
PRI Span: 4 > Bearer Capability (len= 5) [ Ext: 1  Coding-Std: 0  Info transfer capability: Speech (0)
PRI Span: 4 >                              Ext: 1  Trans mode/rate: 64kbps, circuit-mode (16)
PRI Span: 4 >                                User information layer 1: A-Law (35)
PRI Span: 4 > [18 01 89]
PRI Span: 4 > Channel ID (len= 3) [ Ext: 1  IntID: Implicit  BRI  Spare: 0  Exclusive  Dchan: 0
PRI Span: 4 >                       ChanSel: B1 channel
PRI Span: 4 >                     ]
PRI Span: 4 > [70 0b 80 30 37 38 34 33 36 36 35 30 38]
PRI Span: 4 > Called Party Number (len=13) [ Ext: 1  TON: Unknown Number Type (0)  NPI: Unknown Number Plan (0)  '039991122' ]
PRI Span: 4 > [a1]
PRI Span: 4 > Sending Complete (len= 1)
PRI Span: 4 T303 timed out.  cref:32773
PRI Span: 4 q931.c:6415 t303_expiry: Call 32773 enters state 22 (Call Abort).  Hold state: Idle
PRI Span: 4 Fake clearing.  cref:32773
PRI Span: 4 q931.c:9910 pri_internal_clear: alive 1, hangupack 1
Span 4: Processing event PRI_EVENT_HANGUP(6)
    -- Span 4: Channel 0/1 got hangup, cause 18
PRI Span: 4 q931.c:7270 q931_hangup: Hangup master cref:32773
PRI Span: 4 q931.c:7312 q931_hangup: Remaining slaves 0
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i4/039991122-5'
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Executing [039991122@local:2] Hangup("ALSA/default", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (local, 039991122, 2) exited non-zero on 'ALSA/default'
  << Hangup on console >> 
PRI Span: 4 T312 timed out.  cref:32773
PRI Span: 4 Destroying call 0x7f0d84008b20, ourstate Call Abort, peerstate Call Present, hold-state Idle
```

Another problem is this: the incoming calling are "working" because the phone ring(when answer fail), the outcoming calling are not reported by pri debug: what I miss? this is the new extensions.conf

```
[from-dahdi]
exten => _XXXXX.,1,Dial(DAHDI/g14/${EXTEN})
exten => _XXXXX.,2,Hangup()
```

How to define a extension for the outgoing calling?

Comment: maybe try pri debug?

Comment: Tried, i will post the result soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
Was a problem of usb redirection(solved using a pci-e card with usb-2 controller), before i use a usb host redirection(using libvirt) now I redirect the entire usb controller, connect the isdn ta to usb port. Now the isdn softphone can call and receive. I forget to said that the isdn ta was connected to a virtual machine.